# How do I get current CET date and time in Flutter?

Tags: date, flutter, dart

How do I get todays CET date in the order day, month, year in flutter? Is it possible to write it directly in an expand widget? I'm quite new to flutter and coding in general so excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [instant](https://pub.dev/packages/instant) package. I've never used it but it seems to work pretty good. Here's how you can use it,

- Depend on it and run `Packages get`:

```
dependencies:
  instant: ^0.2.1
```

- Import it:

```
import 'package:instant/instant.dart';
```

- Implement it:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
            ),
            body: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Center(
                      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      getDateTime()
                  ])))
            ));
  }

  getDateTime() {
    DateTime cetTime = dateTimeToOffset(offset: 1.0, datetime: DateTime.now()); //current DateTime in CET timezone
    return Text('CET Date: ' + formatDate(date: cetTime, format: 'DDMMYYYY', divider: '/') + '\nCET Time: ' + formatTime(time: cetTime),
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),);
  }
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

**Note:** Seems like the package code does not include CET but it provides you an option to manually set the offset. Package uses the offset to compare the time with UTC. For CET, its 1.0 which is being passed in the implementation above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great. Please mark above as an answer so that it can help others.